# Copying Multiline Text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I know there are a lot of discussions out there about copy and pasting not working when there are multiple lines as it just pastes all on the same row.  I found a lot of fixes when using JQuery, but I am not using JQuery. Was wondering if somebody could help me out?  I am looking for it to paste like this

```
Copy1
Copy1
Copy1
```

instead of

```
Copy1Copy1Copy1
```

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
<title>Central</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    
<div id="Table">

</div>
        
</div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Copy.js"></script>

<script>

window.onload = function() {
    
GetCopy();
   
   
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('CopyButton');

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var b = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[2].textContent;
    
    copyToClipboard(b);
    
  });
}

}

function copyToClipboard(text) {
  var dummy = document.createElement("textarea");
  document.body.appendChild(dummy);
  dummy.value = text;
  dummy.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(dummy);
}


</script>
</html>
```

js

```
function GetCopy() {
var data = '<table id="myTable"> \
<tr class="header"> \
<th>Title</th> \
<th></th> \
<th>Verbiage</th> \
</tr> \
<tr><td>Row 1</td> \
<td><input type="button" class="CopyButton" value="Copy" onclick="" /></td> \
<td>Copy Me 1<br>Copy Me 1<br>Copy Me 1</td> \
</tr> \
<tr><td>Row 2</td> \
<td><input type="button" class="CopyButton" value="Copy" onclick="" /></td> \
<td>Copy Me 2<br>Copy Me 2<br>Copy Me 3</td> \
</tr> \
</table>'
document.getElementById('Table').innerHTML =data; }
```

UPDATE - Here is my updated code that is not pasting correctly for me when I try to pull in a js table

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Copy.js"></script>

<script>
    
window.onload = function() {
    
GetCopy();
   
   
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('CopyButton');

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var b = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[2].textContent;
    
    copyToClipboard(b);
    
  });
}

}

function copyToClipboard(text) {
  var dummy = document.createElement("textarea");
  document.body.appendChild(dummy);
  dummy.value = text;
  dummy.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(dummy);
}


</script>


<div id="container">
<div id="Table">
</div> 
</div>


<style>
td {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
</style>
```

js

```
function GetCopy() {
var data = '<table id="myTable"> \
<tr class="header"> \
<th>Title</th> \
<th></th> \
<th>Verbiage</th> \
</tr> \
<tr><td>Row 2</td> \
<td><input type="button" class="CopyButton" value="Copy" onclick="" /></td> \
<td>Copy Me 1 <br> \
Copy Me 1 <br>\
Copy Me 1<br></td> \
</tr> \
<tr><td>Row 2</td> \
<td><input type="button" class="CopyButton" value="Copy" onclick="" /></td> \
<td>Copy Me 2 <br>\
Copy Me 2 <br>\
Copy Me 3<br></td> \
</tr> \
</table>'
document.getElementById('Table').innerHTML =data; }
```

Comment: upt - Copy1 should be pasted as 3 different rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use line breaks to separate the text and display it with `white-space: pre-wrap` to preserve whitespace instead of displaying all on one line. Additionally, you can use template literals (delimited by backticks) to easily create multiline strings without needing to use `\` to escape the newline character.

Live Example:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    
GetCopy();
   
   
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('CopyButton');

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var b = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[2].textContent;
    
    copyToClipboard(b);
    
  });
}

}

function copyToClipboard(text) {
  var dummy = document.createElement("textarea");
  document.body.appendChild(dummy);
  dummy.value = text;
  dummy.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(dummy);
}

function GetCopy() {
var data = `<table id="myTable"> 
<tr class="header"> 
<th>Title</th> 
<th></th> 
<th>Verbiage</th> 
</tr> 
<tr><td>Row 1</td> 
<td><input type="button" class="CopyButton" value="Copy" onclick="" /></td> 
<td>Copy Me 1
Copy Me 1
Copy Me 1</td> 
</tr> 
<tr><td>Row 2</td> 
<td><input type="button" class="CopyButton" value="Copy" onclick="" /></td> 
<td>Copy Me 2
Copy Me 2
Copy Me 3</td> 
</tr> 
</table>`
document.getElementById('Table').innerHTML =data; }
```

```css
td {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="Table">
</div> 
</div>
Paste Text Here:
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response hev1.  I got this to work when the function GetCopy was on the HTML, but am unable to paste multiple lines when I have a .js table that loads on the page. Do I need to make some tweaks on the js file to make it paste correctly?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] in that case. However, I would recommend modifying your JavaScript to match the code I have provided as an example.

Comment: Dev1 - I updated my code at the top.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @RickD You haven't matched the code I used in my answer; you should be using literal line breaks instead of `<br>`. That is the issue.

Comment: Thanks so much I got it working now.  I used \n in the js table and allowed me to paste multiple lines.

Comment: @RickD Happy to help. (Also, my username is "hev1".)

Comment: sorry about that :)